# Java, BlazeDS, Flex - Error #10566: Cannot create property smallMessage on AcknowledgeMessage?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds, amf

I have a working Flex/Java application, but if I log out of the channelSet and log back in, in the debug console I am seeing numerous instances of this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property smallMessage on mx.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage.
```

The error itself doesn't seem to interfere with app.

The `AcknowledgeMessage` class is not my class -- and I don't know why the Java side and Flex side don't match up with regard to properties on their internal classes.

Any help is appreciated.

Versions:

- Flex 4.1.0.16076
- BlazeDS 4.0.0.14931
- Spring-Flex 1.5.0.RELEASE

Comment: What versions of Flex and BlazeDS are you using?

Comment: Added to original question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are having exactly the same problem in our application. I've managed to hide the error using the following ugly hack.

First, create a class like so:

```
public class FixedAcknowledgeMessage extends AcknowledgeMessage {
    private var _smallMessage : *;

    public function FixedAcknowledgeMessage() { }

    public function get smallMessage() : * {
        return _smallMessage;
    }

    public function set smallMessage(value : *) : void {
        _smallMessage = value;
    }   
}
```

And then, in your startup code, replace AcknowledgeMessage with your fixed one:

```
registerClassAlias("flex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage", FixedAcknowledgeMessage);
```

We also do the same hack for the classes ErrorMessage and AsyncMessage, which seem to suffer from the same problem. I have no idea if this hack may have some negative side effects, and I would love to find a more proper fix for it.

Comment: What is this smallMessage anyway?

Comment: Very good question. The java implementation of AcknowledgeMessage has it as a property, the as3 implementation does not. I guess BlazeDS is the one to blame here...

Comment: When you send an object in AMF, all of the properties of the class must be listed as strings, so that the deserializer knows how to deserialize it. BlazeDS has some AcknowledgeMessage that conforms to IExternalizable, though, and always sends the properties in the same order, so it can skip sending the property names. The smallMessage setter is part of the conversion between the standard AcknowledgeMessage and the compressed one, although why you're getting exceptions is beyond me.

Comment: If its possible to create a fully working application reproducing the problem I will take a look on it, it might be a real bug. my yahoo email account is cornelcreanga.

Answer (score 1):

don't use same name as primary key what you used in the table name...
Use different name .....
 for example......

VO object...

```
public class ColumnNameVO
{    
    public var ifId:int;
    public var formatId:int;
    public var position:int;
    public var name:String;  
    public function ColumnNameVO() { }
}
```

### Table pojo classs:

```
public class ColumnNameVO
{
    public var Id:int;
    public var formatId:int;
    public var position:int;
    public var name:String;  

}
```